# Checking whether a function is even or odd and checking if a function is periodic

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

For given function, for example $f(x)=x^3+x^2-x-1$, to check whether it's even or odd, we have to find $f(-x)$.

Therefore, $f(-x)=-x^3+x^2+x-1$, which proves the function is not odd neither even.

Now, once we have that, how do I check whether the function is periodic?

Comment: What is the definition of period for a function?

Comment: A periodic function is if f(x+P)=f(x).

Comment: So why not just check that?

Comment: I'm not sure what do I take as P?

Comment: Hint: $f(1) = 0$. If the function is periodic with period $P$ (doesn't matter what the value of $P$ is), then there are infinitely many values of $x$ for which $f(x) = 0$, namely $x = 1, 1\pm P, 1\pm 2P, \ldots$. Is it possible for your $f(x)=x^3+x^2-x-1$ to have value $0$ for infinitely many values of $x$? Why or why not?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Good enough for an answer, in my opinion.

Comment: @DilipSarwate I think that it's not possible to have infinitely many values of x to have the value 0 of the function. Why or why not? I'm not sure. I would like to know though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is $f(x) = x^3+x^2-x-1 = 0\,$?

E.g., Hint: $f(1)=0.$

And note $f(x) = (x - 1)(x^2 + 2x + 1) = (x-1)(x+1)^2$. So the only other "zero" of the function, is at $x = -1$: $\quad f(-1) = 0$.

A periodic function with period $p$ (as suggested in the comments: it doesn't matter what the value of $p$ is), has infinitely $x$ such that $f(x)=0,$ and it this case, $f(1) = 0$, there must exist some $p$ such that $ x=1,1\pm p,1\pm 2p, \cdots$.

As Dilip asked above: "Is it possible for $f(x)=x^3+x^2−x−1$ to have the value $0$ for *infinitely* many values of $x$? Why or why not?"

Try graphing $f(x)$ for to develop some intuition about your function; doing so will make the behavior of $f(x)$ immediately apparent. Below, I've included graphs produced by WolframAlpha. As the graphs confirms, there are exactly two values of $x$ at which $f(x) = 0$. So what can you conclude with respect to whether or not $f(x)$ is periodic.

Close up view of function:

[image]

Wider range:

[image]

As the top graph confirms, there are exactly two values of $x$ at which $f(x) = 0$.  And you can see from the graphs that
$f(x)$ is increasing on $x \in (-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$, and it is decreasing only when $x \in (-1, 1)$.

Since $f(x)$ it has exactly two zeros, hence finitely many zeros, $f(x)$ *cannot* be periodic.

Comment: graphing is essential :+)

Comment: Do you have an example where there is a period, just to see what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: A periodic function can be monotonous?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: The polynomial $f$ is increasing or decreasing on some interval of the form $[a,+\infty)$, so can $f$ be periodic function?

Comment: Think not. But I'm not sure. I don't really understand it.
I don't understand the connection between incrementation of the interval with periodic?

Comment: @user2041143, suppose that $f$ is periodic, so there's a constant $T>0$ s.t $f(x+T)=f(x),\quad \forall x$. Now, since the polynomial $f$ is, say, increasing (non constant) on some interval $[a,+\infty)$, we have $f(x+T)>f(x)$: contradiction, same reasoning if $f$ is decreasing.

Answer (score 0):

If you know about polynomial end-behavior, and about its continuity (so boundedness on any closed interval), then you can conclude that $f$ is not periodic.

If not, you can take an arbitrary $P$ and suppose that $f(x+P)=f(x)$ for all $x$. Expand the terms of $$f(x+P)-f(x)=0,$$ and you'll end up with a polynomial in $x$ and $P$ with a factor of $P$. For such a polynomial to be $0$ for **all** $x$, we require $P$ to be $0$, so $f$ isn't periodic.

More simply, note that $$f(x)=x^2(x+1)-(x+1)=(x^2-1)(x+1)=(x-1)(x+1)^2,$$ so $f$ has $2$ real zeroes. If $f$ were periodic, then it would necessarily have infinitely-many zeroes.